# IE10 and anti-aliasing for rotated images

Tags: internet-explorer, css, rotation, transform

I'm looking for a way to do anti-aliasing on a rotated image with a large border on IE10 on the image above.

I've try `-ms-backface-visibility:hidden` which fixes it on Chrome, but it doesn't work and I don't find any other information about IE10

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems not to be a CSS problem but a size one's on IE (maybe in order to avoid big calculation on client browser).

The image was a big one (+2K pixel), and the problem disappears when I reduce it under 1000px.